# Multiple GridViewHeaderRowPresenter

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a TreeListView and I need to visualize multiple header.

|     firstHeader     |    secondHeader  |

|  col1   |  col2     |  col3   | col4   |

I'm using this code:

```
<DockPanel>
  <GridViewHeaderRowPresenter Columns="{StaticResource TaskColumns}" DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
  <ItemsPresenter/>
</DockPanel>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you want to show horizontal treeview ?

Comment: No, just a super header over normal header...

Answer (score 0):

To show a header, we can use HeaderedContentControl.
Eg;

```
 <HeaderedContentControl Header="India" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="10">
        <TreeView>

            <TreeViewItem Header="Cinemas">
                <TreeViewItem Header="Hyderabad">
                    <TreeViewItem Header="Central"/>
                    <TreeViewItem Header="RamaKrishna"/>
                    <TreeViewItem Header="Anand"/>
                </TreeViewItem>

                <TreeViewItem Header="Bhopal">
                    <TreeViewItem Header="DB Mall"/>
                    <TreeViewItem Header="Jyoti"/>
                    <TreeViewItem Header="PVR"/>
                </TreeViewItem>
            </TreeViewItem>

            <TreeViewItem Header="Cinemas">
                <TreeViewItem Header="Hyderabad">
                    <TreeViewItem Header="Central"/>
                    <TreeViewItem Header="RamaKrishna"/>
                    <TreeViewItem Header="Anand"/>
                </TreeViewItem>

                <TreeViewItem Header="Bhopal">
                    <TreeViewItem Header="DB Mall"/>
                    <TreeViewItem Header="Jyoti"/>
                    <TreeViewItem Header="PVR"/>
                </TreeViewItem>
            </TreeViewItem>
        </TreeView>
    </HeaderedContentControl>
```